# Using SharedPreferences for saving Application's Setting

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Lets say, my app has 2 activities.

1. **Activity 1**, the main activity with a button which opens **Activity 2**.
2. **Activity 2**, which is my setting activity and has a **checkBox**.

Now I am saving the value of, if the checkbox is checked or not, using **SharedPreferences**.

Now I want to use this setting value in every other activity, so I am making a **toast** in activity 1 which displays if the checkBox is checked or not.

**Code in activity 1:-**

```
if(new Activity2().getCheckStatus())
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "chcked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not chcked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Activity 2:-**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    CheckBox check =null;

    SharedPreferences settings;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActionBar().setTitle("SETTING");

        setContentView(R.layout.setting);

         check =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
         check.setOnClickListener(this);

         settings = Activty2.this.getSharedPreferences("checkBox",0);

        Boolean a = settings.getBoolean("isChecked", false);
            check.setChecked(a);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View)
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {

        case R.id.checkBox:


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

            if(!check.isChecked())
            {
                check.setChecked(true);
                editor.putBoolean("isChecked", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                check.setChecked(false);
                editor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);
                editor.commit();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public boolean getCheckStatus() 
    {
        SharedPreferences mysettings;
        try{
             mysettings = Activity2.this.getSharedPreferences("checkBox",0);
        }catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return mysettings.getBoolean("isChecked", false);


    }
}
```

**Activity2** is just for showing if the **checkBox** is checked or not, if it is then show so and if there is any changes then save it using **SharedPreferences**.

My reason for catching **NullPointerException** is, as I am showing **toast** in **activity1**, which is my main activity, so when ever the app is run first time, there will be no SharedPref until I have run `onCreate()` of activity2. So if I am getting the exception it means the app is running for the first time or the user has not until now opened **Activity2**. If so return the default **false** value, if not then `catch()` is never called and I get the value stored.

**MyProblem:-**
As you guessed, It's not working. The checkBox is working fine,whenever I open Activity2 it shows me the previous set value but the toast is always showing **not checkd** .

Please tell me , whats the error here or is there any other simpler way to save android app user settings and access them anywhere else in the app.

Thanks.

Comment: You should not construct a new Activity using the new operator. Ever. It should always be created using an Intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, move the SharedPrefs read to activity1, as this

<strike>`if(new Activity2().getCheckStatus())`</strike>

will be deadly if Activity 2 is bigger.

So this:

```
public boolean getCheckStatus() 
{
    SharedPreferences mysettings;
    try{
         mysettings = getSharedPreferences("checkBox",0);
    }catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return mysettings.getBoolean("isChecked", false);
}
```

goes to Activity 1. Albo, make `"checkBox"` a constant value (public static final String).

Try now.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the same in other activities (open shared preferences) and check if your checkbox is setted or not:

```
settings = Activity.this.getSharedPreferences("checkBox",0);
Boolean a = settings.getBoolean("isChecked", false);
```